# Has anyone implemented a way to move selected items from one list view box to another in pyqt 5?

Tags: python, listview, pyqt5, multi-select

I am trying to implement something like one in the picture below in PyQt  5- python, I am not necessarily looking for the up/down button but, with an OK button to get the list of selected items. I don't see any similar examples implemented for pyqt5, I was wondering if anyone has some direction?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332487/6622587) I detail the response and the implementation in C ++, now I will only translate it to PyQt:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TwoListSelection(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TwoListSelection, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setup_layout()

    def setup_layout(self):
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.mInput = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.mOuput = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        self.mButtonToSelected = QtWidgets.QPushButton(">>")
        self.mBtnMoveToAvailable= QtWidgets.QPushButton(">")
        self.mBtnMoveToSelected= QtWidgets.QPushButton("<")
        self.mButtonToAvailable = QtWidgets.QPushButton("<<")

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addStretch()
        vlay.addWidget(self.mButtonToSelected)
        vlay.addWidget(self.mBtnMoveToAvailable)
        vlay.addWidget(self.mBtnMoveToSelected)
        vlay.addWidget(self.mButtonToAvailable)
        vlay.addStretch()

        self.mBtnUp = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Up")
        self.mBtnDown = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Down")

        vlay2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay2.addStretch()
        vlay2.addWidget(self.mBtnUp)
        vlay2.addWidget(self.mBtnDown)
        vlay2.addStretch()

        lay.addWidget(self.mInput)
        lay.addLayout(vlay)
        lay.addWidget(self.mOuput)
        lay.addLayout(vlay2)

        self.update_buttons_status()
        self.connections()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_buttons_status(self):
        self.mBtnUp.setDisabled(not bool(self.mOuput.selectedItems()) or self.mOuput.currentRow() == 0)
        self.mBtnDown.setDisabled(not bool(self.mOuput.selectedItems()) or self.mOuput.currentRow() == (self.mOuput.count() -1))
        self.mBtnMoveToAvailable.setDisabled(not bool(self.mInput.selectedItems()) or self.mOuput.currentRow() == 0)
        self.mBtnMoveToSelected.setDisabled(not bool(self.mOuput.selectedItems()))

    def connections(self):
        self.mInput.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.update_buttons_status)
        self.mOuput.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.update_buttons_status)
        self.mBtnMoveToAvailable.clicked.connect(self.on_mBtnMoveToAvailable_clicked)
        self.mBtnMoveToSelected.clicked.connect(self.on_mBtnMoveToSelected_clicked)
        self.mButtonToAvailable.clicked.connect(self.on_mButtonToAvailable_clicked)
        self.mButtonToSelected.clicked.connect(self.on_mButtonToSelected_clicked)
        self.mBtnUp.clicked.connect(self.on_mBtnUp_clicked)
        self.mBtnDown.clicked.connect(self.on_mBtnDown_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_mBtnMoveToAvailable_clicked(self):
        self.mOuput.addItem(self.mInput.takeItem(self.mInput.currentRow()))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_mBtnMoveToSelected_clicked(self):
        self.mInput.addItem(self.mOuput.takeItem(self.mOuput.currentRow()))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_mButtonToAvailable_clicked(self):
        while self.mOuput.count() > 0:
            self.mInput.addItem(self.mOuput.takeItem(0))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_mButtonToSelected_clicked(self):
        while self.mInput.count() > 0:
            self.mOuput.addItem(self.mInput.takeItem(0))        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_mBtnUp_clicked(self):
        row = self.mOuput.currentRow()
        currentItem = self.mOuput.takeItem(row)
        self.mOuput.insertItem(row - 1, currentItem)
        self.mOuput.setCurrentRow(row - 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_mBtnDown_clicked(self):
        row = self.mOuput.currentRow()
        currentItem = self.mOuput.takeItem(row)
        self.mOuput.insertItem(row + 1, currentItem)
        self.mOuput.setCurrentRow(row + 1)

    def addAvailableItems(self, items):
        self.mInput.addItems(items)

    def get_left_elements(self):
        r = []
        for i in range(self.mInput.count()):
            it = self.mInput.item(i)
            r.append(it.text())
        return r

    def get_right_elements(self):
        r = []
        for i in range(self.mOuput.count()):
            it = self.mOuput.item(i)
            r.append(it.text())
        return r
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    list_selection = TwoListSelection()
    list_selection.addAvailableItems(["item-{}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
    def on_clicked_left():
        print(list_selection.get_left_elements())
    def on_clicked_right():
        print(list_selection.get_right_elements())
    l_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
        text="print left elements",
        clicked=on_clicked_left
    )
    r_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
        text="print right elements",
        clicked=on_clicked_right
    )
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    hlay.addWidget(l_button)
    hlay.addWidget(r_button)
    lay.addLayout(hlay)
    lay.addWidget(list_selection)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: this works great, I was just wondering how to get the list of items from the selected items from the right side? I mean like after clicking an "ok" button which captures all the selected ones.

Comment: @user9529330 I've already added the get_right_elements method that returns a list of items from the list on the right side

Comment: I am trying to call the TwoListSelection class on my QMainWindow class to add the two list view as a widget, but every time the iPython console is closed with a message reading "An error occurred while starting the kernel". I am unsure what's causing this, was wondering if something similar on your end too?

Comment: @user9529330 I do not use ipython, and by not knowing your code I can not help you, post a new question clearly indicating the complete code you use so the community can help you